# Dynamic access to elements of the layout

Tags: android

I have a question that is driving me crazy.

I have a large number of buttons (10, more or less) on my screen, inside a TableRow.

I need to access them, and I had planned to perform through a loop.

Access to one, is very easy, adding this:

```
boton7 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn7)
```

My question is, if you can dynamically set the id string (R.id.Btn7) to put in a can get the buttons for, and for example, change the color .... something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <10; i + +) {
   Button eachBoton= (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn + i);
   eachBoton. setBackgroundColor (Color.Red);
}
```

That, of course, does not work .... my question is if anyone knows how exactly the chain can be mounted

```
R.id.Btn + i
```

to work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `Resources#getIdentifier()` to get a resource identifier for the given resource name:

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(
    "Btn"+i,
    "id",
    this.getContext().getPackageName());
Button button = (Button) findViewById(resourceId);
```

Alternately you can prepare an array with all the ids you need and access elements of that array. This is more efficient:

```
private final int[] btns = {R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3, R.id.btn4, ...}
...
Button button = (Button) findViewById(btns[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this really useful for dynamically loading resources.

Answer (score 4):

Give an identifier to your layout ("layout" in the example below) and then iterate over all the touchable children by using `getTouchables`. If it's a button, change the color.

```
View layout = findViewById(R.id.layout)
ArrayList<View> touchables = layout.getTouchables();
for (View b : touchables) {
    if (b instanceof Button) {
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
    }
}
```